# If $x+y+z=1000$ and $x,y,z \geq 50$ then find the number of possible integer solutions for x,y and z?

Tags: combinatorics

This is a typical star and bar problem, but I cannot figure out how to deal with the condition that $x,y,z \geq 50$. Please Help...

Comment: What are your thoughts? We aren't here to solve your homework, on which you have put no effort.

Comment: So $x-50\ge 0$ etc., and $x-50+y-50+z-50=$ what?

Comment: Indeed, just perform a transform of x' = x - 50 etc. to get a "homogeneous" stars and bars problem.

Comment: @JaideepKhare Bro if you dont have any interest in this why did you open it in the first place...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have

$$(x-50)+(y-50)+(z-50)=850$$

where $x-50$, $y-50$ and $z-50$ are non-negative integers.

Use star and bar.

Comment: Can you please guide me how to apply it now...? i am not asking for the formula i want the logic behind it...

Comment: This is equivalent to $a+b+c=850$ with $a$, $b$, $c$ being non-negative integers. Using standard star and bar, the number of solutions is $\binom{850+2}{2}$.